# mysqldump: flush-privileges option

Tags: mysql, backup, permissions, mysqldump

I'd like to get some clarification about the `--flush-privileges` option for mysqldump.

Here's the description of the option from the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_flush-privileges):

```
--flush-privileges    
Send a FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement to the server after dumping the mysql database.
This option should be used any time the dump contains the mysql database and any other
database that depends on the data in the mysql database for proper restoration.
```

When it says that it sends the flush statement **after dumping** the database, I read that to mean that the data, schema, etc. is **dumped** into the backup file and then the flush statement is sent to the database that was just dumped (**after** it was **dumped**).

I was wondering what dumping the data, etc. did that required the privileges to be flushed, so I started searching for an explanation to be sure when and why to use it.

As I read various answers, it occurred to me that it would make sense if the flush statement was being included in the dump file. Then after the contents of the file was **loaded into** a database, the flush privileges statement was run to update the settings after the new info was imported.

So, how does it work?
A) Flush the source database **after dumping** the data to a file? If so, why is this necessary?
B) Flush the destination database after **importing** the contents of the dump file?
C) Something other than the possibilities I've described?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is misleading.  I read it exactly the same way you do, which isn't what the utility does.

Adding `--flush-privileges` causes mysqldump to include the following *in the backup file,* after dumping the mysql schema...

```
--
-- Flush Grant Tables
--

/*! FLUSH PRIVILEGES */;
```

...which of course causes the server where the dump is being restored to re-read the potentially-changed grant tables.

And, that's all it does.

Confirmation of this can be found in the source code for mysqldump "10.13" (the version bundled with MySQL Server 5.5.30):

```
if (flush_privileges && using_mysql_db == 0)
{
  fprintf(md_result_file,"\n--\n-- Flush Grant Tables \n--\n");
  fprintf(md_result_file,"\n/*! FLUSH PRIVILEGES */;\n");
}
```

The `using_mysql_db == 0` comparison was confusing at first, but it turns out to be the return value from a string comparison function where "0" means "identical."

Comment: This is the very answer needed for this question. +1 !!!

Comment: Great Answer, thanks for providing documentation and additional details.

Answer (score 5):

In light of [Michael-sqlbot's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35849/877), try to keep one more thing in perspective.

The only time using `--flush-privileges` is good for a mysqldump is when

- you dump `--all-databases` (which includes the `mysql` schema)
- you dump the `mysql` schema only.

What's even more superficial about the `--flush-privileges` option for mysqldump is that you can just append the command to the output yourself like this:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --routines --triggers > MySQLData.sql
echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" >> MySQLData.sql
```

This assumes you cared to remember this. That's why the `--flush-privileges` option was added to mysqldump as a reminder.

Comment: Good note about it being needed only if the mysql schema is dumped. It was hinted at by the `using_mysql_db == 0` check that @Michael-sqlbot explained.